# Should current DNS servers respond to obsolete DNS records?

Tags: dns

[Here is a list of obsolete DNS record types.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#Obsolete_record_types)

1. Should I restrict my DNS server to not respond to these query types?
2. Why are current public DNS servers responding to these query types?

Comment: I'm not sure what the security angle is here

Comment: The general rule of thumb for any service is to only expose that which you need.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I restrict my DNS server to not respond to these query types?

So long as you don't have any DNS records of these types in your zones -- which you probably don't -- there's no need to "restrict" anything. If your DNS server is queried for records of these types, it will (correctly) respond that none exist.